# Flutter, how do I get the app display name localized?

Tags: flutter, localization, app-store, app-store-connect

So I have a Flutter app. In both Apple app store and Google play, I have localized the display name so that it has different names in different languages. How do I read this programmatically from within the app, so that I know which name I should refer to when mentioning the app? I tried package_info_plus wit the `appName` attribute, but it doesn't seem to be the display name?